# Matrix equation with symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be symmetric matrices.

I've encountered the equation $B^T B \Sigma A = 0$

Where $A$ and $B$ are non-zero, and $\Sigma$ is positive semi-definite.

Using just this information, is it possible to prove that $B \Sigma A = 0$ (ie can we remove the transposed $B$?)

Comment: What's the point of putting transpose on the symmetric matrix $B$?

Comment: Well, no, it's not enough. For example, the kernel of a linear operator may contain nonzero elements.

Comment: @user10354138 Just me being dumb I suppose

Comment: @Sean_Roberson doesn't that contradict the answer just posted?

Comment: @Xiaomi It holds under certain conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes if the matrix $B\Sigma A$ is real.

*Proof*.  Since $B^T B\Sigma A=0$, we have $A^T\Sigma^TB^T B\Sigma A=0$ and that is $(B\Sigma A)^T(B\Sigma A)=0$.  But the trace of the LHS is the Frobenius norm of the matrix $B\Sigma A$.  QED.

This can go wrong in the complex case, e.g., $A=\Sigma=I$ and
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}1&i\\i&-1\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $B^2=0$ without $B=0$.

Comment: Hi just to clarify - this proves it because a matrix $A$ has Frobenius norm $0$ if and only if $A= 0$, correct? Sorry, I have not encountered such a norm before now. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Yes.  The Frobenius norm is a norm (it is the usual Euclidean norm if you write out the matrix entries), and one of the defining property of a norm is that having norm 0 means you started out with 0.

Comment: Oops, yes missing a minus sign.